# jquery datatable server side processing with both input and column filtering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am not good at javascript and I want to know how to filter the columns in datatable with both input and column filtering using PHP.

I can only filter by input. But, I can't do both.

Here is my working code with input server side filtering.

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
                var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
            });

            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "order": [
                    [0, 'desc']
                ],

                "ajax": "server_processing.php"
            });

            table.columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

// DB table to use
$table = 'test_table';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'username', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'firstname', 'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'lastname', 'dt' => 3 ),
    array(
        'db' => 'status',
        'dt' => '4',
        'formatter' => function($d, $row) {
            if($d == 1) {
                return 'Success';
            } else if($d == 2) {
                return 'Pending';
            } else {
                return 'Fail';
            }
        }
    ),
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'testdb',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
    * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
    */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

$result = SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns);

echo json_encode($result);
```

ssp.class.php is supported in datatable forum.

Thanks a lot in advance. Please answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean you can't do column filtering? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I can do column filtering with only input boxes. What I can't do is column filtering with both input and select boxes.